# Is it possible to configure HTTP to work on HTTPS port only? I don't want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, so that I can avoid one network call

Tags: iis

Is it possible to configure HTTP to work on HTTPS port only? I don't want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, so that I can avoid one network call(301).

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but don't do it.

Comment: I want to do it in testing environment. No plans to do it in PROD. Can you help me on achieving it?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Your testing environment should mimic production as closely as possible. Why would your testing environment care about one or two 301 calls every once in a while?

Comment: For clarification: Do you want to use both HTTP and HTTPS on port 443, or do you mean to configure your HTTPD (IIS) to only listen on HTTPS?

Comment: @ Gerald Schneider Yes

Comment: @Yashh which one of these two possibilities?

Comment: I want both HTTP and HTTPS on port 443.

Comment: You'll be disappointed, then.

Answer (score 5):

HTTP and HTTPS are different protocols. You can't have them listening the same port at the same time, and having an HTTP server on HTTPS port 443 would be very unconventional. I can't see any actual reason to avoid a single HTTP 301 response. It consumes less resources than even initiation of the TLS protected HTTPS connection.

You could decrease the amount of those calls by enabling HSTS; then, after the initial HTTPS connection, the browser would start doing this internally.

Comment: HSTS Preload would also help.